# show full attendance by specifying present days and absent days in a date interval

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have an attendance log of each employee, the employee may be present only a few days. I want to show the present days and absent days in a given date interval.

for example the given interval is :

`$from = "2019-03-01";`

`$to = "2019-03-05";`

**This is the data record:**

```
[
 {      
   "id": 1310,
   "empid": 3,
   "check_in": "11:56",
   "check_out": "17:25",
   "date": "2019-03-02",
   "time_long": "5:28"
 }, 
 {      
   "id": 1311,
   "empid": 3,
   "check_in": "08:00",
   "check_out": "16:00",
   "date": "2019-03-04",
   "time_long": "8:00"
 },
...
]
```

I expect the output to be as following:

I will show the output in html.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>NO</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Check In</th>
            <th>Check Out</th>
            <th>Time Long</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2019-03-01</td>
            <td>X</td>
            <td>X</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2019-03-02</td>
            <td>11:56</td>
            <td>17:25</td>
            <td>5:25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>2019-03-03</td>
            <td>X</td>
            <td>X</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>2019-03-04</td>
            <td>08:00</td>
            <td>16:00</td>
            <td>8:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>2019-03-05</td>
            <td>X</td>
            <td>X</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What have you tried and what were the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that $input has the data in the format you specified.

This is in Json Format so first of all you need to decode it.

Next you need re-format the array so that keys are the dates.

Next you will need to change the Dates into DateTime Object.

Now you can loop through these dates using for loop. Inside the for loop you need to check that for the given date does a key exist in your reformatted array. If yes, then use that to populate. Otherwise print X.

Below is the whole code

```
$results = json_decode($input);

$formatResults = array();
foreach( $results as $result) {
    $date = $result->date;
    $formatResults[$date] = $result;
}

$from = "2019-03-01";
$to = "2019-03-05";

$begin = new DateTime( $from );
$end   = new DateTime( $to );
?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>NO</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Check In</th>
            <th>Check Out</th>
            <th>Time Long</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php    
    $loopCount = 0;
    for($i = $begin; $i <= $end; $i->modify('+1 day')){
        $loopCount++;
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'. $loopCount . '</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $i->format("Y-m-d") . '</td>';
            if( isset ( $formatResults[ $i->format("Y-m-d") ] ) ) {
                echo '<td>'. $formatResults[ $i->format("Y-m-d") ]->check_in . '</td>';
                echo '<td>'. $formatResults[ $i->format("Y-m-d") ]->check_out . '</td>';
                echo '<td>'. $formatResults[ $i->format("Y-m-d") ]->time_long . '</td>';
            } else {
                echo '<td>X</td>';
                echo '<td>X</td>';
                echo '<td>X</td>';
            }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```